# Silverlight style trigger throwing error in blend

Tags: silverlight

I am styling a listbox in silverlight and the trigger I am making will not work in Blend. Here is the code.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
    </Style>
```

Blend just says "The member Triggers is not recognized or is not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because the `Style` class does not have a `Triggers` collection.  Only derivatives of `FrameworkElement` have a `Triggers` collection and in Silverlight only `Loaded` trigger is recognized.

Comment: Do you suggest a way that I can do the same thing I am currently doing with this code?